# How to Install multiple version of Drush?

Tags: drush

I have Drush 6 installed in my system.

I need to install Drush 5 too (hosting doesn't support Drush6), how do I install Drush5 without uninstalling Drush6 and use both of them simultaneously, Drush6 for local development and Drush5 for SFTP.

Comment: What OS are you on for your local environment? I don't know what features in Drush 6 you need, 5.9 is pretty stable and works for the practically everything I do.

Comment: I use ubuntu. I work as freelancer so in one project I was recommended to use Drush6 for their make files (Im not expert in those things). Since then I have Drush6, but for another project in Pantheon servers they don't support Drush 6, I need Drush 5

Comment: I actually work with clients on Pantheon all the time and I'm currently on Drush 6.1.0 and haven't run into issues yet. Pantheon also has a set of their own drush tools called Terminus. Could you update your question with the errors you're actually getting?

Comment: I am also using Terminus and aliases from Pantheon, but while using their alias `drush sa` gives me the sites available and when I do `drush @sitename.env status` it gives **Unexpected** results. I have been in contact with Pantheon support team, they (Ricky Pugh) say its because I am using Drush 6. I wonder how you are working, can you verify you get same status from `drush SITE status` for both local environment and Pantheon environment?

Comment: It might be your alias. When I run `drush site status` normally, I get the "`to suppress this error, add the option --strict=0`", so I add it and run again, and get back the status of the site as normal.

Comment: well I always use the `--strict=0`. The problem might be with my alias files I downloaded from Pantheon dashboard, but I said them, they say its NOT due to the alias but, because I am using Drush6, so, I want to install Drush5 too and verify if they are right or I need to swear from top of my lungs.

Comment: @Sara They're right; I have the same issues using Drush 6/7 with Pantheon (the error about `db-url`). FWIW it happens on all types of account (Free, Personal, Pro, Enterprise). [Related issue on Pantheon](http://help.getpantheon.com/pantheon/topics/using_drush_60_pantheon_how_set_strict0_globally)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your .bashrc:

```
alias drush5=/path/to/drush5/drush
alias drush6=/path/to/drush6/drush
```

With this, `drush5` will give you Drush 5, `drush6` will give you Drush 6, and `drush` will give you whichever of these appears first on your `$PATH`.

Rename your aliases to suit.

Comment: so you mean download the Drush folder and make a bash profile. Ok, I was hoping some solution like `apt-get install`. I'll give it a try

Comment: voila, it works... thanks... Yes Pantheon is crap... Acquia uses Drush 4.7 still when I run Drush6 for SFTP, it has no issues.\

Comment: I wouldn't be so harsh on Pantheon; based on what I saw in the related issue that Clive cross-posted, it sounds like their aliases are fine, and it's a Drush issue with db-url.  Someone should post an issue in the Drush queue for resolution in Drush 6 and Drush master.

Comment: I was getting `-bash: drush10: command not found` error. I closed and reopened my putty, then the issue is gone.

Answer (score 1):

One option on Debian/Ubuntu is to use the ["alternatives" system](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) to register multiple different versions as alternatives, and switch between them. That way, the command `drush` can be switched to point to different versions, without having to change any scripting you've done elsewhere.

However, this isn't as useful as you'd think, as switching between them is still a bit cumbersome: `update-alternatives` requires you to provide the full path to the version of Drush you want to make temporarily "primary".

With that in mind, [this blogpost](http://www.jpstacey.info/blog/2014-04-07/switching-between-drush-major-versions) (disclaimer: my own) explains how to script the alternatives system to switch between Drush versions using something like `switchdrush VERSION` and sudo access. If you're not on a Debian-based *nix, then that scripting should be adaptable, to instead just change any `/usr/bin/drush` symlink.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you J-P!

The link to [http://www.jpstacey.info/blog/2014-04-07/switching-between-drush-major-versions.html](http://www.jpstacey.info/blog/2014-04-07/switching-between-drush-major-versions) helped me a lot on Ubuntu.

However, you have to adapt the grep-command in case you are using a localized (non-English) OS/Terminal.

In my case (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - German) i had to replace

```
command=`update-alternatives --display drush | grep "priority $version" | awk
```

With

```
command=`update-alternatives --display drush | grep "Priorität $version" | awk
```